# Input filed loses or Remove focus when soft keyboard open in Ionic and Angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This is my Code:

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content class="login_bg">
        <div class="login_logo"><img src="img/login_logo.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="register_page">
                <input type="email" name="name" placeholder="Email" ng-model="login_info.forgetmail" ng-enter="forgetPassword()" />
             <div class="clearfix">
                 <a class="signup" ng-click="forgetPassword()">Submit</a>
             </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Problem: When I input in the input field, the soft keyboard opens and it removes focus from the input field. I have to retype on the input field. Please help me for this issue. I have tried but cannot find the  exact answer for this..

Comment: Hello Davin do you have any solution for this. i tried a lot for this but cannot found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late, but I have found this right now just searching for resolving my own problem.

I'm resolving this problem with this (you need to add `id="email"` to your `input` tag):

```js
var email = document.getElementById("email");
angular.element(window).on('resize', function(event){
    var touched = angular.element(email).hasClass('ng-touched');
    if (!touched) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

When you click on an `input`, that fires the soft keywoard, firing a `resize` event and is this `resize` event who «steals» the focus of the `input` (in fact, it steals the focus of the entire `window` object).

Preventing the default behavior when a `resize` event for `window` is fired prevents from it stealing the focus. I also take into account if the `input` has the class `ng-touched`, because this avoids `preventDefault()` being executed everytime the soft keyboard opens and closes.
In fact, with this condition, seems that `preventDefault()` only fires the first time the soft keyboard is launched. But this seems to be enough: the `input` wouldn't lose their focus again when soft keyboard appears.

I tried this in Firefox for Android, Android stock, Lightning and Chrome.

Hope this will help you or @parvindra if you're still suffering this issue.

Funny thing about this is that the mentioned *Lightning*, a lightweight browser for Android, isn't affected with this hell of annoying behavior. It works out of the box.